# Filter out incorrect JSON before parsing

Tags: android, json, jsonexception

I'm trying to parse some JSON that is being sent to me as an API response however for some reason it keeps giving it to me with a "one" at the beginning even though the rest is perfectly fine e.g.

```
"one"{"position":"0", "level":"0", "is_active":"0", "name":"Root",
"children": [{
    "position":"0"...
```

This gives me the exception:

`org.json.JSONException: Value one of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Is there anything I can do to get rid of it?

Comment: Not that I know of.

But is the API something that is written by you?

I'm not sure how you are reading it, but if it came in as a string, you could just remove that part of the string and pass the string into a JSON parser afterwards.

Comment: No, it's the Magento API. Your idea sounded good as it was coming in as a string so I used `string.replace("one", "");` but I get the same exception with a space between `Value  of...`

Comment: Where is the `Value of` come from in the JSON? A name, or a value?

Comment: It's part of the exception `org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: Is there anything else in the file that looks out of place? Are you able to show the file?